# Is there a Xamarin Mvvmcross Android Shared Element Navigation example?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I'm trying to get this [animation/transition](https://developer.android.com/training/material/animations.html#Transitions) working in my Xamarin Android application with Mvx.

I have a recyclerview with cards. When tapping on a card, I now call:

```
private void TimeLineAdapterOnItemClick(object sender, int position)
{
    TimeLineAdapter ta = (TimeLineAdapter) sender;
    var item = ta.Items[position];

    int photoNum = position + 1;
    Toast.MakeText(Activity, "This is photo number " + photoNum, ToastLength.Short).Show();

    ViewModel.ShowDetails(item.Id);
}
```

I'm trying to find out how to translate this java navigation with transition to Xamarin with Mvvmcross:

```
ActivityOptionsCompat options = 
   ActivityOptionsCompat.MakeSceneTransitionAnimation(this, imageView, getString(R.string.activity_image_trans));

startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
```

I know that within Mvx you can make use of custom presenters, but how do I get hold of, for example, the ImageView of the tapped Card within the RecyclerView which I would like to 'transform' to the new ImageView on the new Activity?

Thanks!

.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a Xamarin Mvvmcross Android Shared Element Navigation
>   example?

I do not believe so.

> I know that within Mvx you can make use of custom presenters, but how
>   do I get hold of, for example, the ImageView of the tapped Card within
>   the RecyclerView which I would like to 'transform' to the new
>   ImageView on the new Activity?

The easiest way that I can think of to achieve the sharing of control elements you want to transition is via the use of [view tags](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.styleable.html#View_tag) and a presentation bundle when using `ShowViewModel`.

I would suggest making some changes to your Adapter Click handler to include the view of the `ViewHolder` being selected *(See [GitHub repo](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/PHSharedElement) for example with EventArgs)*. That way you can interact with the `ImageView` and set a tag that can be used later to identity it.

```
private void TimeLineAdapterOnItemClick(object sender, View e)
{
    var imageView = e.FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView);
    imageView.Tag = "anim_image";

    ViewModel.ShowDetails(imageView.Tag.ToString());
}
```

Then in your ViewModel, send that tag via a presentationBundle.

```
public void ShowDetails(string animationTag)
{
    var presentationBundle = new MvxBundle(new Dictionary<string, string>
    {
        ["Animate_Tag"] = animationTag
    });

    ShowViewModel<DetailsViewModel>(presentationBundle: presentationBundle);
}
```

Then create a custom presenter to pickup the `presentationBundle` and handle the creating of new activity with the transition. The custom presenter which makes use of the tag to find the element that you want to transition and include the `ActivityOptionsCompat` in the starting of the new activity. This example is using a `MvxFragmentsPresenter` but if you are not making use of fragments and using `MvxAndroidViewPresenter` the solution would be almost identical (Override Show instead and no constructor required).

```
public class SharedElementFragmentsPresenter : MvxFragmentsPresenter
{
    public SharedElementFragmentsPresenter(IEnumerable<Assembly> AndroidViewAssemblies)
        : base(AndroidViewAssemblies)
    {
    }

    protected override void ShowActivity(MvxViewModelRequest request, MvxViewModelRequest fragmentRequest = null)
    {
        if (InterceptPresenter(request))
            return;

        Show(request, fragmentRequest);
    }

    private bool InterceptPresenter(MvxViewModelRequest request)
    {
        if ((request.PresentationValues?.ContainsKey("Animate_Tag") ?? false)
            && request.PresentationValues.TryGetValue("Animate_Tag", out var controlTag))
        {
            var intent = CreateIntentForRequest(request);

            var control = Activity.FindViewById(Android.Resource.Id.Content).FindViewWithTag(controlTag);
            control.Tag = null;

            var transitionName = control.GetTransitionNameSupport();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(transitionName))
            {
                Mvx.Warning($"A {nameof(transitionName)} is required in order to animate a control.");
                return false;
            }

            var activityOptions = ActivityOptionsCompat.MakeSceneTransitionAnimation(Activity, control, transitionName);

            Activity.StartActivity(intent, activityOptions.ToBundle());
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

`GetTransitionNameSupport` is an extension method that just does a platform API check when getting the `TransitionName`.

```
public static string GetTransitionNameSupport(this ImageView imageView)
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= BuildVersionCodes.Lollipop)
        return imageView.TransitionName;

    return string.Empty;
}
```

The final step would be to register the custom presenter in you `Setup.cs`

```
protected override IMvxAndroidViewPresenter CreateViewPresenter()
{
    var mvxPresenter = new SharedElementFragmentsPresenter(AndroidViewAssemblies);
    Mvx.RegisterSingleton<IMvxAndroidViewPresenter>(mvxPresenter);
    return mvxPresenter;
}
```

---

You can check the [repo on GitHub](https://github.com/Plac3hold3r/PHSharedElement) which demonstrates this example. The solution is designed so that the presenter does not have to care about the type of the control that is being transitioned. A control only requires a tag used to identify it. The example in the repo also allows for specifying multiple control elements that you want to transition (I did not want to include more complexity in the example above).

[image: Shared Element Demo]

Comment: Thank you so much for spending this amount of time and efforts to make this clear to me and the Mvx open-source community.

Comment: @JonHendrix, no problem. I had always wanted to try out this animation, and when I read your question I thought I might as well try it out now :)

Comment: @Plac3Hold3r You might want to look at https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/2022 which adds support for this.